# Why child_1 will print before parent?

Tags: c, fork

I have a C code that a parent process will `fork()` a child process:

```c
int main(){
    pid_t child_1;
    child_1 = fork();
    if (child_1 > 0){
        printf("Parent: (PID %d)\n", getpid());
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else if (child_1 == 0){
        printf("child: %d", getpid());
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Parent: (PID 1234)
child: 1235
```

But if I removed the `\n` in the `printf` of parent, the output would become:

```
child: 1235Parent: (PID 1234)
```

I'm not sure why and I've tried on different OS and the output is the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because process are likely executed in parallel, strictly speaking you shouldn't expect any particular order.

Comment: @Cheatah Thanks for such a quick response. So it is not caused by the `\n` in `printf()`, and it will happen sometimes if I do have the `\n` if I understand correctly? But I tried to run both again and again, I always get the same result with or without the `\n` character.

Comment: `printf` is line buffered. Which means it won't actually output until a newline is encountered or an explicit flush is done (such as when the process exits). So in your case removing the newline changes when the parent process actually outputs. Since the parent waits for the child to exit it means the parent flush will occur after the child has outputted.

Comment: @kaylum That makes a lot of sense, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is line buffered. Which means it won't actually output until a newline is encountered or an explicit flush is done (such as when the process exits). So in your case removing the newline changes when the parent process actually outputs. Since the parent waits for the child to exit it means the parent flush will occur after the child has outputted.